# using appsheet getting error " "COMPUTED_VALUE""

Tags: google-sheets-formula, google-appsheet

I do have this formula

```
={"R Per Maand";ARRAYFORMULA(IF(LEN(B2:B),I2:I*GOOGLEFINANCE("CURRENCY:USDZAR"),))}
```

that when running from google sheet is working, but when I run it from appSheet app, it gives error
="COMPUTED_VALUE" with this "Array result was not expanded because it would overwrite data in L3."
There is nothing in L3 till I run it from appsheet app.

The sheet that needs to get the data in in googlesheeet,

I even did try and use new sheet, use formula, then add in new cell, just as number, without formula, but still give same answer.

Answer (score 1):

Edit the table column in Appsheet, and under the Auto Compute section, delete the "COMPUTED_VALUE" from the Spreadsheet Formula field. This is sometimes added automatically by Appsheet, from arrayformula fields in the spreadsheet when generating or regenerating schemas.